# driver update selection in new AppCenter - do I need two nvidia drivers (340 375)?

Tags: updates, appcenter, nvidia

after running the elementaryOS update which brings the new AppCenter, I found in the update tab a new section "drivers". It offers in my case to install (not update) three drivers: intel-microcode, nvidia-340 and nvidia-375. I have a notebook with intel on-chip-grafic and an external nvidia grafic chip (geforce 840M). So two drivers, one for intel and one for nvidia seems ok but do I really need two drivers for nvidia?

Normally I tend to accept all updates suggested on the update tab, while I am used to choose from the software options presented on the other tab (startpage) for what I think could be useful to me. So I am puzzled, if the new AppCenter offers on the update tab options that are not made for my computer or if it detects my hardware and I should follow the suggestions and install two different drivers for the nvidia-grafic-card?

On the ubuntu help-page I found the information, that I would need for the nvidia geforce 400 to 1000 series the 375 driver (see https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/Grafikkarten/Nvidia/nvidia/) I did not found any information, that I should install two different drivers.
I installed the intel and the nvidia-375 drivers and it seems to work. But still I am puzzled if I need to install the second nvidia-driver, since it is still offered on every system update.

I am running elementary OS 0.4.1 Loki on acer TMP645 with  i7-5500U CPU @ 2.40GHz and Intel Corporation Broadwell-U Integrated Graphics (rev 09)
NVIDIA Corporation GM108M [GeForce 840M] (rev a2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you don't need to and, in fact, you can't have multiple versions of a driver installed. You have an option to install other versions because the newest drivers do not always work best.

If you run into any problems with nvidia drivers you can install older versions and see how they work. A currently installed version will be replaced automatically.

Comment: Thanks, I am happy that I did the right thing. Seems it is just a sub-optimal User Experience of the new AppCenter though.